# Stack Overflow account exists but cannot login

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, merge-accounts

There is something weird going on with my Stack Overflow account.

Last week I logged out of my Stack Overflow account and then logged in again. When I logged in, it opened another account with another user nickname and reputation, which I had created about two years ago. I removed my Gmail login from that new account and tried to login again with my Gmail account. It asked me to choose a nickname, I entered my nickname and my first account was recovered. But now I cannot login to that account from another computer or another browser. I am trying to add new login; I open Edit profile&Settings, but it shows me an error page saying

> Oops! Something Bad Happened!

I tried to merge two accounts, filled out the merge form, but again "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" appeared. What can I do about that? The account I want to recover is https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102416/bigo.

Comment: Click "contact us" in the footer and send a message the Stack Exchange team directly.  That is probably the best way to handle this.

Comment: @Oded wasn't there a bug with the merge process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used stackoverflow contact page and the problem was solved by the support team. It looks like there was a problem in the database because of a previous merge and they fixed it. Everything is ok now.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact to get in contact with support...